# Accessing the default path for the user keychain folder via terminal

Tags: terminal, keychain, macos

By default, user-domain keychains are placed in `~/Library/Keychains`. Can this path be changed and, if so, is there a terminal command to print out the configured location?

For context, I have a ruby gem and I'm trying to play good citizen rather than hardcoding the location.

(I know you can add a keychain from any location, but I'm referring to the default path that keychains reside in)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's stored here per-user:  /Users/[user]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist

This plist seems to list all of your keychain references.